# phpBB: Is there any mod for voting up Threads?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, plugin, phpbb, reputation

I'm looking for a mod that enables users to **vote up threads**. I.e. not replies within threads, but threads *themselves*.

Ideally, I'd prefer to have **only up-voting**; no 1–5 stars, up/down-votes, multiple-choices, etc. just up-voting (something that's akin to Google's +1 button).

Is there anything like this out there? I've tried searching for this but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think this mod can help you, maybe with some additionnal modifications

http://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/mod/topic_evaluation/

Source of information :

http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=2132826